# How to kill a windows process by Id in C?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, signals, kill-process

I searched many websites for this issue but I couldn't find a good answer.
I'm getting a pid from a text file and then trying to kill that process with `Kill()` function but when I try to compile I see this Error:

```
.\stopErraticord.c: In function 'main':
.\stopErraticord.c:41:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'kill' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             kill(pid, SIGTERM); // Terminate the process
             ^~~~
C:\Users\armin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMB0Jar.o:stopErraticord.c:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to `kill'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I found some results to fix it for linux but couldn't find any for windows :(

here is the code:

```
            if ((fptr = fopen("pid.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
                printf("[!] Error Opening pid.txt");
                exit(1); // Exit if pointer returns NULL
            }

            fscanf(fptr, "%[^\n]", pid_s);
            fclose(fptr);
            int pid = atoi(pid_s); // Convert pid from string to integer
            kill(pid, SIGTERM); // Terminate the process
            printf("[>] Process with Id: %d terminated", pid);
```

I wanna know how to fix this error but my main goal is to terminate that process with a C function not with `System()` function.
so if you know how to fix this error or you know a better way to terminate a process I'll appreciate if you help me with that.

Comment: How did you compile and link this file?  [mcve]. Did you build with Cygwin GCC, that would provide POSIX functions like `kill` in its headers and libc?  It's a POSIX function, not ISO C, so it's not surprising that a plain/native Windows compiler like MinGW wouldn't define it, or maybe even have a `signal.h` at all.  Also, a much simpler and more standard example would be to write a `main` that takes the PID as `atoi(argv[1])`.  The file open/close stuff is just cluttering your [mcve].

Comment: The Windows system call is [`TerminateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess)

Comment: to use the `kill()` function, you need to have the following `include` statements: `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <signal.h>`

Comment: the `pid` is different for each execution of the code, so how does the current `pid` get into the file?